# how to download large file on G-wan?

Tags: g-wan

I use G-wan download files from directory 'www' ,it can download the files size less than 16M,if the files size is 16M, the G-wan is wrong:

```
Signal        : 11:Unknown SIGSEGV problem
Signal src    : 128:.
errno         : 0
Thread        : 1
Code   Pointer: 0000004081a8 (module:gwan, function:??, line:0)
Access Address: 000000000000

Registers     : EAX=7f1dbc0afa4e CS=00000033 EIP=0000004081a8 EFLGS=000000010287
            EBX=7f1dc24af000 SS=d5ab0400 ESP=7f1dd59acd30 EBP=7f1dbc0afa4e
            ECX=ffe3e5a1746a4230 DS=d5ab0400 ESI=1c997c47a33a4e FS=00000033
            EDX=1c1a5e8b984000 ES=d5ab0400 EDI=7f1dbc0afa3e CS=00000033

Module         :Function        :Line # PgrmCntr(EIP)  RetAddress  FramePtr(EBP)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Segmentation fault
```

thanks for Gil.
Os: debian 7,rhel6.4
dwonload the file size is 80M ,file:0.0.0.0_8080/#0.0.0.0/www/MFC-7340-inst-B2-zh.EXE.this is trace content:

```
Wed, 14 Aug 2013 02:57:36 GMT: start
Wed, 14 Aug 2013 02:58:00 GMT  12 127.0.0.1
GET /MFC-7340-inst-B2-zh.EXE HTTP/1.1^M
Host: localhost:8080^M
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20130806 Firefox/17.0 Iceweasel/17.0.8^M
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8^M
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5^M
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate^M
Connection: keep-alive^M
Cookie: SESS49960de5880e8c687434170f6476605b=iOQ_BgGEgAWbhB9zA0U5jZbEOXzmu3nkzhyBW00GJGM; Drupal.tableDrag.showWeight=0; Drupal.toolbar.collapsed=1; MOIN_SESSION_800_ROOT=8a77c4a58fefc1ad6b6830b5bc51ca680a480bae^M
^M
Wed, 14 Aug 2013 02:58:02 GMT: signal 11: Unknown SIGSEGV problem
source        : 128:Kernel
thread        : 0/2
state         : SEND
client        : 127.0.0.1:58472
request       : /MFC-7340-inst-B2-zh.EXE
----------------
----------------

Signal        : 11:Unknown SIGSEGV problem
Signal src    : 128:.
errno         : 0
Thread        : 0
Code   Pointer: 0000004081a8 (module:gwan, function:??, line:0)
Access Address: 000000000000

Registers     : EAX=7f85482fd0c0 CS=00000033 EIP=0000004081a8 EFLGS=000000010293
                EBX=7f8565501000 SS=6cd00400 ESP=7f856cbfcd30 EBP=7f85482fd0c0
                ECX=ffeea9eeb46863d5 DS=6cd00400 ESI=11d59693c9ef4b FS=00000033
                EDX=1156114b9a1e8b ES=6cd00400 EDI=7f85482fd0b0 CS=00000033

Module         :Function        :Line # PgrmCntr(EIP)  RetAddress  FramePtr(EBP)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: adding to @Gil "answer": version would also be interesting, and the environment you're serving from (e.g. is it a ramdisk? a virtualized host? ...)

Answer (score 0):

G-WAN has been used to serve much larger file sizes. Could you specify the exact file size you have used so we can try to duplicate this issue?

Generating a graceful crash report (your trace) is as easy as using the crash script examples given with the download archive so we need a bit more information to start answering your question.

Comment: version 4.3.14 64bit, os:debian7 x86_64

Comment: I was asking for the *"exact file size you have used"*, not for the program version and OS revision.